# How to expose webservice through domain

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, mydomain, get

I am setting up an webservice which needs to be accessible from outside. I have created a domain and have my class a public. How do I give acces to the object?

Apex

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Salesproducts/*')
global with sharing class WebserviceSalesproducts {
    @HttpGet
    global static Sales_Product__c  getSalesproductsByProductCode () {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        // grab the ProductCode from the end of the URL
        String ProductCode = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Sales_Product__c  result =  [SELECT id,name
                                     FROM Sales_Product__c 
                                     WHERE name = :ProductCode];
        return result;
    }
}
```

I would expect to be able to access the webservice by

```
https://domain.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Salesproducts/niceproduct
```

I currently get the error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Errors>
<Error>
<errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
<message>Session expired or invalid</message>
</Error>
</Errors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you configure your site/community to expose the REST API to "guest users" (which is a security risk), you need to consider authentication against your REST API. Please follow the guidance in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm).